# How to put delay in javascript so form could submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form which i am making from javascript and posting from there.
But before form could submit the page is reloaded again.
when i m inserting alert after form.submit(); then it let form to be submit

here is the code

```
 myfunction: function {

     var form = document.createElement("form");
     product = document.createElement("input");
     product.value = JSProduct;
     product.name = "Product";
     form.action = "myForm.aspx";
     form.method = "post";
     form.appendChild(product);
     document.body.appendChild(form);
     form.submit();
  }
```

before form could be post the page reloads again but if i put alert after form.submit() it works fine and redirects to next page otherwise it reloads the same page if i dont put alert.
So i think submiting a form takes time so  **i want to ask you if know how i could hold or put certain delay after submiting form**

Thanks

Comment: "i think submiting a form takes time" - I dont think this is the case here.

Comment: So could you tell me what is the main problem i m missing ??

Comment: can you create a fiddle. I dont see any issue here.

Comment: Thanks Problem is resolved Thanks for Your help Guys :)

Comment: Please edit the comment and add answer here. So that others can be helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this all is a javascript each button and from the button i was calling this function like.

```
 <form >
   ...
   <Button id="something" onclick="myfunction()" />
   ...
 </form>
```

Something like this ..

So what making it hard or problematic is the form i m creating inside myFunction() is nested form and that causing the problem because its parent form is getting posted and action on that form is the same page.

**So i have to change the button into anchor tag and which does not let parent form to submit.
Or we can also change button type = button instead of submit so when myFunction() executes the inner form get posted on form.submit().**

I know its stupid what ever it is but this happens.
Thanks Guys for Your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use setTimeout function after form submitting.

```
setTimeout(function(){var x="2 seconds"},2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am edited your code and add "setTimeout(function(){alert("Hello")},2000);" function which run after 2 sec. And you can change its interval.

```
myfunction: function {

 var form = document.createElement("form");
 product = document.createElement("input");
 product.value = JSProduct;
 product.name = "Product";
 form.action = "myForm.aspx";
 form.method = "post";
 form.appendChild(product);
 document.body.appendChild(form);
   setTimeout(function(){
       form.submit();
     },2000);

}
```

Hope its will help.
Let me know it worksing or not.

Answer (score 0):

Check your button requests a return value, like this:

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: return myfunction()">
```

also try adding:

```
return false;
```

to the end of your function.

Comment: Nope my buton also in script and where i m calling a function inside that function i m building a form and submitting th same before that function over